# Saving already existing file with added file extension not prompting overwrite message

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, overwrite

For my GUI project that I am doing, I am trying to get the Save mechanisms down nicely. I am currently working on Overwriting files, and I've run into a bit of a problem.

Here's a test case that I've created:

`Save current file using Save As. When prompted for a file name, give an existing file name with an added file extension.`

Let's assume that an already existing file is called: `test.config`

If I type in: `test` and press save, an overwrite prompt pops up, which is what I want.

If I type in: `test.config` and press save, **NO** overwrite prompt pops up, and the program continues. This is not what I want. I want an overwrite prompt to pop up and warn the user.

I've been searching around various websites and Javadocs for Files and I can't seem to figure out how to check if the file exists if the user types in an extra extension.

Here is some code that might help you guys understand:

```
...

int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(Dialogc.this);
if(returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Error saving file. \nFile not saved.");
        return 1;
}

// Get file name
file = fc.getSelectedFile();

/* Check if file exists */
if(file.exists()) {
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
        "File already exists. Overwrite?", "Overwrite Prompt",  
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}
else {
    // If it doesn't exist, create new file
}
...
```

**NOTE:** I do have methods that add or remove the extension. Should I use these to maybe help with checking if the given file already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `approveSelection(...)` method to confirm the over writing of the file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;

public class FileChooserSave
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser( new File(".") )
        {
            public void approveSelection()
            {
                if (getSelectedFile().exists())
                {
                    int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                        this,
                        "Do You Want to Overwrite File?",
                        "Confirm Overwrite",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    if (n == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                        super.approveSelection();

                }
                else
                    super.approveSelection();
            }
        };

        chooser.setSelectedFile( new File("something.rob") );
        int returnVal = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);


        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
           System.out.println(chooser.getSelectedFile() );
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize in advance; I'm fairly new to Java. I understand overriding methods but I'm not sure how this can fix my problem? I have no problem prompting the overwrite messages, it's only when I try to save as `existing_filename.config`, note the **.config**, that I don't get the message.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the reverse problem... if the user doesn't type the extension, it does not prompt.  I add the extension later if the user didn't type it.  So in your case if the user typed "test", my code would save the file as "test.config".  I'm assuming yours works the same way?

For me to fix it I had to also add the extension during the approval... so firstly:

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(){
@Override
public void approveSelection(){

    File f = getSelectedFile();
            String filestring = f.toString();

            String[] left_side_of_dot = filestring.split("\\.");

             f = new File(left_side_of_dot[0] + ".config");


    if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG){
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(YOUR_Frame,"The file exists, overwrite?","Existing file",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
        switch(result){
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                super.approveSelection();
                return;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                return;
            case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                cancelSelection();
                return;
        }
    }
    super.approveSelection();
 }
};
```

then also before saving:

```
String noxtfilename = filename.substring(0, filename.length()-7);
    File file = new File(noxtfilename);
    fc.setSelectedFile(file); }
 FileNameExtensionFilter filefilter = new  FileNameExtensionFilter("Config File (*.config)","config");

 fc.setFileFilter(filefilter);


    int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(YOUR_Frame);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            String filestring = file.toString();

            String[] left_side_of_dot = filestring.split("\\.");

             file = new File(left_side_of_dot[0] + ".config");
```